# Suming up total amount of fees by year and splitting the data into a table with year on top and total at the bottom

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here are the 2 tables structures (minified for a MCVE - they have more rows not needed here):

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ FEES ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

fee_id +++ fee_amount +++ fee_date   +++ fee_student_ID +++ fee_paid +++

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1      +++  200       +++ 2019-12-05 +++ 1              +++ N       ++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2      +++  200       +++ 2020-01-05 +++ 1              +++ N       ++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
3      +++  200       +++ 2020-01-05 +++ 1              +++ N       ++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
4      +++  250       +++ 2020-01-05 +++ 2              +++ N       ++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
5      +++  250       +++ 2020-02-05 +++ 2              +++ N       ++++
```

The tables are linked -> **fee_student_ID = student_ID**

```
++++++++++++++++++++ STUDENTS +++++++++++++++++++++

student_ID +++ student_name   +++ student_phone +++ 

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1          +++ John Doe       +++ 123456789     +++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2          +++ Jane Doe       +++ 987654321     +++
```

With my SQL query, I can retrieve and order the data (I need only rows where "paid" is late/coming soon). What I need is:

1. group by year
2. sum amount by year

I achieve #1 like this (and it works as expected):

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $adminDBuser, $adminDBpwd);

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT tbl_fees.*, tbl_students.*, YEAR(tbl_fees.fee_date) AS yearfee 
FROM tbl_fees, tbl_students 
WHERE tbl_fees.fee_student_ID=tbl_students.student_ID 
AND tbl_fees.fee_paid='N' 
AND tbl_fees.fee_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
ORDER BY tbl_fees.fee_date ");

$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach( $results as $row ) {

if ($row['yearfee'] != $yearfee) {
echo "<tr colspan=\"5\" class=\"table-title-year\"><td class=\"table-title-year\">
". $row['yearfee']."
</td></tr>";
//**-- adds a row on top of the list, with the YEAR, and splits the data => OK
}

echo"<tr><td>$fee_id</td><td>",my_formated_date($fee_date),"</td>
<td><a href=\"/student-data.php?id=$student_ID\">$student_name</a></td>
<td>$fee_amount</td><td>$fee_paid</td></tr>\n\r";

}
```

Now, what I want to add is another, at the bottom of each "year split".
This row would show the total amount of unpaid/soon to be paid fees.
Like below, which is the expected outcome:

```
-----------------------------------------
YEAR : 2019
-----------------------------------------
1 --- John Doe --- 2019-12-05 --- 200 ---
-----------------------------------------
TOTAL : 200
-----------------------------------------
YEAR : 2020
-----------------------------------------
2 --- John Doe --- 2020-01-05 --- 200 ---
3 --- Jane Doe --- 2020-01-05 --- 250 ---
4 --- John Doe --- 2020-02-05 --- 200 ---
5 --- Jane Doe --- 2020-02-05 --- 250 ---
-----------------------------------------
TOTAL : 900
-----------------------------------------
```

**How do I achieve the above table, using SQL query or PHP?**

I've searched the [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) (and other related topics in the doc) and [this tutorial](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot) (amongst others), but can't find a way to adapt it to my case.

I've tested something like this, with a single year or for each known separate year (all throwing errors anyway...):

- SUM(tbl_fees.fee_amount) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tbl_fees.fee_date) = 2019) AS yearlySumTotal1
- SUM(tbl_fees.fee_amount) WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tbl_fees.fee_date) = '2019' AS yearlySumTot1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$results = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'date' => '2019-12-05', 'amount' => 200],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'date' => '2020-01-05', 'amount' => 200],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'date' => '2020-01-05', 'amount' => 250],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'date' => '2020-02-05', 'amount' => 200],
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'date' => '2020-02-05', 'amount' => 250],
];

$year = '';
$total = 0;

echo '<pre>';
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $rowyear = substr($row['date'], 0, 4);

    if ($year != $rowyear) {
        // avoid displaying in the begining of the table
        if ($total) {
            display_total_row($total);
        }

        display_year_row($rowyear);

        $year = $rowyear;
        $total = 0;
    }

    echo '-----------------------------------------' . PHP_EOL;
    echo sprintf('%d --- %s --- %s --- %s ---', $row['id'], $row['name'], $row['date'], $row['amount']) . PHP_EOL;
    echo '-----------------------------------------' . PHP_EOL;

    $total += $row['amount'];
}

// display last total
display_total_row($total);

echo '</pre>';

function display_year_row($year) {
    echo '-----------------------------------------' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'YEAR : ' . $year . PHP_EOL;
    echo '-----------------------------------------' . PHP_EOL;
}

function display_total_row($total) {
    echo '-----------------------------------------' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'TOTAL : ' . $total . PHP_EOL;
    echo '-----------------------------------------' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've just tested and it seems very fine, and much more easy for me to understand and modify :) even though I'll study and learn from the others, I might (after more testing), go for this. I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi, long SQL make me headache but yeah there is no harm to use it if it responds to the need since it may be more compact and faster in execution. But I think always prefer the solution which is easier to understand, it don't need to be my answer, it may be the other too so it is up to you =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need aggregation if you want the totals.

```
SELECT YEAR(f.fee_date) AS yearfee, SUM(f.fee_amount)
FROM tbl_fees f JOIN
     tbl_students s
     ON f.fee_student_ID = s.student_ID AND
        f.fee_paid = 'N'  AND
        f.fee_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY YEAR(tbl_fees.fee_date);
```

If you want both the original data and the rollup:

```
SELECT YEAR(f.fee_date) AS yearfee, s.student_id, f.fee_date, f.fee_amount
FROM tbl_fees f JOIN
     tbl_students s
     ON f.fee_student_ID = s.student_ID AND
        f.fee_paid = 'N'  AND
        f.fee_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(f.fee_date) AS yearfee, NULL, NULL,
       SUM(f.fee_amount)
FROM tbl_fees f JOIN
     tbl_students s
     ON f.fee_student_ID = s.student_ID AND
        f.fee_paid = 'N'  AND
        f.fee_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY YEAR(tbl_fees.fee_date)
ORDER BY yearfree,
         (fee_date is null) desc,
         fee_date;
```

This should interleave the totals with the original data.

Comment: using the 2nd example: it works, but shows the yearly amount on the 2nd row, right after the year. And I lose some student data, like name and other needed stuff. Any idea to improve?

Comment: @OldPadawan . . . This answer is based on your "expected outcome".  You can add additional columns in the first subquery.  Just remember to add `NULL` values for them in the second.

Comment: I'll test that, but it'll take time, it's far beyond my knowledge and skills at this time :) I'll study and learn from it though!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have ticked @ankabot answer because it was much more easier for me to understand it and use/modify it. But I'll study yours to learn from it!

Comment: @OldPadawan . . . It is usually much more efficient to do that work within the database.  That said, I can understand how someone less familiar with databases would prefer the slower approach.

Answer (score 0):

You csn use a rather big query

```
SELECT
`fee_id`, `student_name`, fee_date , YEAR(fee_date), SUM(fe.sumfee),SUM(fey.sumfeeeyear)
 FROM FEES f INNER JOIN STUDENTS S ON f.fee_student_ID = student_ID 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT  SUM(`fee_amount`) sumfee, `fee_student_ID`, YEAR(fee_date) yearoffee FROM FEES 
            GROUP by  `fee_student_ID`,YEAR(fee_date)) fe
  ON fe.yearoffee = YEAR(fee_date) AND fe.`fee_student_ID` = f.`fee_student_ID`
 INNER JOIN (SELECT  SUM(`fee_amount`) sumfeeeyear, YEAR(fee_date) yearoffee FROM FEES 
            GROUP by  YEAR(fee_date)) fey
  ON fey.yearoffee = YEAR(fee_date)   
GROUP BY `fee_id`,fee_date,`student_ID`, `student_name`, YEAR(fee_date)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE  FEES (
>   `fee_id` INTEGER,
>   `fee_amount` INTEGER,
>   `fee_date` VARCHAR(10),
>   `fee_student_ID` INTEGER,
>   `fee_paid` VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO  FEES
>   (`fee_id`, `fee_amount`, `fee_date`, `fee_student_ID`, `fee_paid`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '200', '2019-12-05', '1', 'N'),
>   ('2', '200', '2020-01-05', '1', 'N'),
>   ('3', '200', '2020-01-05', '1', 'N'),
>   ('4', '250', '2020-01-05', '2', 'N'),
>   ('5', '250', '2020-02-05', '2', 'N');
>
> CREATE TABLE STUDENTS (
>   `student_ID` INTEGER,
>   `student_name` VARCHAR(10),
>   `student_phone` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO STUDENTS
>   (`student_ID`, `student_name`, `student_phone`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'John Doe', '123456789'),
>   ('2', 'Jane Doe2', '987654321');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `fee_id`, `student_name`, fee_date , YEAR(fee_date), SUM(fe.sumfee),SUM(fey.sumfeeeyear)
>  FROM FEES f INNER JOIN STUDENTS S ON f.fee_student_ID = student_ID 
>  INNER JOIN (SELECT  SUM(`fee_amount`) sumfee, `fee_student_ID`, YEAR(fee_date) yearoffee FROM FEES 
>             GROUP by  `fee_student_ID`,YEAR(fee_date)) fe
>   ON fe.yearoffee = YEAR(fee_date) AND fe.`fee_student_ID` = f.`fee_student_ID`
>  INNER JOIN (SELECT  SUM(`fee_amount`) sumfeeeyear, YEAR(fee_date) yearoffee FROM FEES 
>             GROUP by  YEAR(fee_date)) fey
>   ON fey.yearoffee = YEAR(fee_date)   
> GROUP BY `fee_id`,fee_date,`student_ID`, `student_name`, YEAR(fee_date)
> ```
>
> ```
> fee_id | student_name | fee_date   | YEAR(fee_date) | SUM(fe.sumfee) | SUM(fey.sumfeeeyear)
> -----: | :----------- | :--------- | -------------: | -------------: | -------------------:
>      1 | John Doe     | 2019-12-05 |           2019 |            200 |                  200
>      2 | John Doe     | 2020-01-05 |           2020 |            400 |                  900
>      3 | John Doe     | 2020-01-05 |           2020 |            400 |                  900
>      4 | Jane Doe2    | 2020-01-05 |           2020 |            500 |                  900
>      5 | Jane Doe2    | 2020-02-05 |           2020 |            500 |                  900
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2672c8a5b78fc90bcd3a6342ad0fd4b9)*

Comment: Thanks for the help! Checking this after Gordon's and I'll let you know :)

Comment: this works, but doesn't give me the expected output, as it's missing the upper and lower row, with the year and sum :/

Comment: Could you edit the example and show me what you mean, it should loose anything because it is grouped ny `fee_id`

Comment: Right above my bolded question is the expected output, with the row *year* before the data, and the row *total* after the data.

Comment: the php is quite easy Save the year in very loop and when it changes set the new Totakl fee from the last column.